# Lisp interactive emacs multiplying incorrectly

Tags: emacs, numbers, lisp, elisp, bignum

I'm running the following code on Emacs Lisp Interaction:

```
(defun square (x) (* x x))
(square (square (square 1001)))
```

which is giving me `1114476179152563777`. However, the `((1001^2)^2)^2` is actually `1008028056070056028008001`. 
How is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Emacs Lisp doesn't implement bignums, it uses the machine's integer type. The range of integers it supports is between `most-negative-fixnum` and `most-positive-fixnum`. On a 64-bit system, `most-positive-fixnum` will be 2<sup>61</sup>-1, which has about 20 decimal digits.

See [Integer Basics](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Integer-Basics.html#Integer-Basics) in the Elisp manual.

The correct result of your calculation is 25 digits, which is much larger than this. The calculation overflows and wraps around. It should be correct modulo 2<sup>62</sup>.

You could use floating point instead. It has a much larger range, although very large numbers lose precision.

```
(square (square (square 1001.0)))
1.008028056070056e+24
```

Answer (score 13):

@Barmar's answer is accurate for Emacs versions < 27.

In Emacs 27 bignum support has been added.  NEWS says:

> ** Emacs Lisp integers can now be of arbitrary size.
>   Emacs uses the GNU Multiple Precision (GMP) library to support
>   integers whose size is too large to support natively.  The integers
>   supported natively are known as "fixnums", while the larger ones are
>   "bignums".  The new predicates 'bignump' and 'fixnump' can be used to
>   distinguish between these two types of integers.
>
> All the arithmetic, comparison, and logical (a.k.a. "bitwise")
>   operations where bignums make sense now support both fixnums and
>   bignums.  However, note that unlike fixnums, bignums will not compare
>   equal with 'eq', you must use 'eql' instead.  (Numerical comparison
>   with '=' works on both, of course.)
>
> Since large bignums consume a lot of memory, Emacs limits the size of
>   the largest bignum a Lisp program is allowed to create.  The
>   nonnegative value of the new variable 'integer-width' specifies the
>   maximum number of bits allowed in a bignum.  Emacs signals an integer
>   overflow error if this limit is exceeded.
>
> Several primitive functions formerly returned floats or lists of
>   integers to represent integers that did not fit into fixnums.  These
>   functions now simply return integers instead.  Affected functions
>   include functions like 'encode-char' that compute code-points, functions
>   like 'file-attributes' that compute file sizes and other attributes,
>   functions like 'process-id' that compute process IDs, and functions like
>   'user-uid' and 'group-gid' that compute user and group IDs.

and indeed using my 27.0.50 build:

```
(defun square (x) (* x x))
square

(square (square (square 1001)))
1008028056070056028008001
```

Comment: And there goes ten minutes of my life staring at my Emacs 26 instance wondering why I'm getting overflow errors. Thanks for making sure to note this only works in 27+.